# Is Earth's Orbit and relation between the Sun and the Moon are properly described in Quran?

Tags: imaan

Atheists say that, In Quran the Orbits of Sun and Moon are cleared but why not of Earths?
Again they argued with a verse of Quran that the everything is created as pairs by God.So they are saying that Sun and moon are created as pairs though as a point of view orbit concept these are funny.

They also say, As they don't find the description of earth's orbit in Quran,that Quran deals with the Geocentric concept of Cosmos that is proved wrong.

I want to know that is there any verse in Quran that also say about Earth's orbit?
Again What Quran actually explains between the relation of the Sun and Moon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not.

> <sup>1</sup> Alif, Lam, Meem.
>   <sup>2</sup> This is the Book about which there is no doubt, a guidance for those conscious of Allah -
>   <sup>3</sup> Who believe in the unseen, establish prayer, and spend out of what We have provided for them,
>   <sup>4</sup> And who believe in what has been revealed to you, [O Muhammad], and what was revealed before you, and of the Hereafter they are certain [in faith].
>   <sup>5</sup> Those are upon [right] guidance from their Lord, and it is those who are the successful.
>
> — [Al Baqarah 1-5](https://legacy.quran.com/2/1-5)

The Qur'an is a book of guidance to the path of Allah, the religion of Islam. It is not, and has never been, a textbook on astrophysics. Anyone who rejects it because of that is missing the point entirely.

So I suppose the real question is, why are you letting atheists tell you what the book of Allah means?

Comment: See that,Atheists try to term the Quran as written by Human beings.So they say that several civilization had idea about some concept of orbit & they argued that Quran's such speech might be borrowed from them.